# The set of point where limit function is finite

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Prove that the set of points at which a sequence of measurable real-valued functions converges (to a finite limit) is measurable.

**Proof:**

Let $f_n(x):X\to \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of real-valued measurable functions and $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$ for $x\in X$. We have to show that $\{x\in X: |f(x)|<\infty\}$ is measurable.

Using Cauchy criterion we get: $f_n(x)$ converges to a finite limit **iff** $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ $\exists N=N(n)$ such that $\forall k,p\geqslant N$ we have $|f_k(x)-f_p(x)|<\frac{1}{n}$.

Here we see that $N$ depends on $n$, i.e. $N:=N(n)$. And I have the following problem: wee see that

$$E=\bigcap \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup \limits_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcap \limits_{k,p\geqslant N}\{x: |f_k(x)-f_p(x)|<\frac{1}{n}\}.$$
$x\in \text{RHS}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ we get that $x$ belongs to inner union $\Rightarrow$ $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ $\exists \tilde{N}\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x$ belongs to inner intersection.
Here's one problem worries me.

How to understand that $\tilde{N}$ is the same as $N$?

Sorry if this topic is repeated but this question seems to me interesting.

Comment: It is not true that $N$ depends on $n$ as $n$ is the *variable* here. I'd rather say $N$ depends on $x$. BTW you finished PMA and started RCA now?

Comment: @Vim, Originally Cauchy criterion states that "$\forall \varepsilon>0$ $\exists N$ ... but this $N$ depends on $\varepsilon$. P.S. Yes I finished PMA and started RCA

Comment: @Vim, When we fixed $x$ our $N$ depends on $\varepsilon$ and $x$

Comment: @Vim, In above example i took $\varepsilon_n=1/n$

Comment: do you mean $1/k$? I see you have used $n$ to index $f_n$.

Comment: @Vim, yeah $1/k$ :)

Comment: All I can see is that if  I turn the def'n of $E$ into "mathematical English" it says  that $x\in E$ iff the sequence $(f_j(x))_j$  satisfies the Cauchy criterion. So you're done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a matter of grinding through the equivalences.

You just need to show that $f_n(x)$ is Cauchy **iff** $x \in E$.

If $f_n(x)$ is Cauchy, then for all $n$ there is some $N$ such that for all
$k,p \ge N$ then $|f_k(x)-f_p(x)| < {1 \over n}$.

Let $A_{n,k,p} = \{x | |f_k(x)-f_p(x)| < {1 \over n} \}$.

Then if $f_n(x)$ is Cauchy, then for all $n$ there is some $N$ such that
$x \in \cap_{k,p \ge N} A_{n,k,p}$.

Then if $f_n(x)$ is Cauchy, then for all $n$,
$x \in \cup_N \cap_{k,p \ge N} A_{n,k,p}$.

And finally, if $f_n(x)$ is Cauchy, then $x \in E= \cap_n\cup_N \cap_{k,p \ge N} A_{n,k,p}$.

Now suppose $x \in E$. Then for all $n$, we have
$x \in \cup_N \cap_{k,p \ge N} A_{n,k,p}$.

Hence for all $n$, there is some $N$ such that $x \in \cap_{k,p \ge N} A_{n,k,p}$.

And finally, for all $n$ there is some $N$ such that for all
$k,p \ge N$, $x \in A_{n,k,p}$, or equivalently
$|f_k(x)-f_p(x)| < {1 \over n}$.

Comment: 1) Here $E$ is intersection+union+intersection as in above post? 2) "If $f_n(x)$ is Cauchy, then for all $n$ there is some $N$ such that for all
$k,p \ge N$ then $|f_k(x)-f_p(x)| < {1 \over n}$." I guess that here the index $n$ and $n$ are not relative.

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) The $n$ in $f_n$ is not the other $n$. Bad choice of symbol on my part.

Comment: "Then if $f_n(x)$ is Cauchy, then for all $n$ there is some $N$ such that
$x \in \cap_{k,p \ge N} A_{n,k,p}$.

Then if $f_n(x)$ is Cauchy, then for all $n$,
$x \in \cup_N \cap_{k,p \ge N} A_{n,k,p}$."

Why they are equivalent? From second line we get that $\exists M$ such that $x \in \cap_{k,p \ge N} A_{n,k,p}$. Why this $M$ must be equal to above $N$? This is the main question!

Comment: The symbol used is irrelevant. You just need **some** $N$ (or whatever).

Comment: I guess that I have understood it. Since $x\in F_M$ for some natural $M$ then $x\in \cup_{N\in \mathbb{N}}F_N$. Right? It immediately follows from definition of union.

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that, in examining whether two sets are equal, we are essentially examining the property of each of their elements, here $x$, but not $N$ or $\tilde N$. All we care about is: for a point $x\in E$, and for each $k$, does there always *exist one natural number* $N(x,1/k)$ (whose exact value we don't care) such that $|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|<1/k$ as long as $m,n>k$? If so then $E\subset \{ x\mid f_n(x)\,\text{converges}\}:=F$. Conversely, we ask, for each $x\in F$, such that $f_n(x)$ is a Cauchy sequence, does it always qualify as an element in $E$? Then we have to do some "for any/for all" arguments, but again, we don't really need to care about the exact values arising in them.

Comment: Note that in my above post my $N$ does not depends on $n$, it depends on $x$. This seems weird.

Comment: Also how you get that $E\subset F$? You know the fact that $N$ and $\tilde{N}$ can be different worries me.

Comment: @RFZ $F$ as I defined is the set of all convergence points. What I mean is if certain conditions are confirmed then we conclude $E\subset F$. And in fact, you don't need to care about the exact values of $N$ which can just  depend on free choice, you should focus on $x$ instead. Even if the two values differ, you can simply take max for both, and nothing changes, isn't it? So as you can see what matters here is the existence, not the value.